# json_encode- not the right type

Tags: php, json

I have the following array: I want to have pic id and 48 as a json type;desired output: {"picid":48}

```
$result=
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => picid
            [1] => 48
        )

    [1] => 1
)
```

but

> json_encode($result[0])
>
> returns the following: ["picid","48"]

Am I doing anything wrong?

Please let me know if you need more clarification!

Comment: where this `sceneid` came from?

Comment: just corrected! dorry about that!

Comment: What it returns *is* valid JSON.

Comment: how can I change it to {"picid":"48"}

Comment: Surely you're looking for the KEY to be 'picid' and the value to be 48, when constructing your array to encode?

Comment: Why would you want to change it @user3399784?

Comment: thats the requirement which is given to me! they want it in this format  {"picid":"48"}

Comment: Do they want that specific format, or just valid JSON? It really makes no sense.

Comment: Loop through the array and assign the value of index 0 to the key of index 1. Then encode that to json

Comment: they specified the mentioned format!

Comment: `$new[$result[0][0]]=$result[0][1];` output : `{"picid":48}`

Comment: Where is your array coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array is constructed incorrectly.

```
echo(json_encode(array('picid' => 48)));
```

produces the output you desire in the json. Modify your array construction accordingly.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the array save for the way that the OP wants to output JSON. What if the array cannot be modified?

Comment: Nice dude! Thanks:) I will mark it once it let me !

Comment: They want a specific output, and the above code produces that.

Comment: The code produces what the OP wants, but that has nothing to do with the array being constructed incorrectly.

Comment: This looks right to me, so I upvoted.  Either modify the array construction as this answer suggests, or create a new array with the desired construction.

Comment: It certainly isn't scalable.

Comment: way too complicated: `echo '{"picid":48}';`

Comment: I'm not suggesting the OP use the *exact* code I posted. It merely demonstrates that the array construction being used in the original question wasn't outputting the desired result. An array using 'picid' as the key, and then the value, will do. He can then go down the road of [0]['picid'] = 48, [1]['picid'] = 301, or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I did it doesn't produce what he wants but is structured I think.

```
class picture
{
    var $pic;

    var $num;

}

$picture = new picture();

$picture->num = 45;
$picture->pic = "name";

echo json_encode($picture);
```

the out put is

```
{"pic":"name","num":45}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    foreach($result as $r){
        $item[$r[0]]=$r[1];
        $allItems[]=$item;
    }
?>
```

You now have an array ($allItems) that will have the value of index 0 as the key and the value of index 1 as the value, which will output the json format you desire

```
<?php
    echo json_encode($allItems[0]);
?>
```